# No HttpMessageConverter for [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode] and content type [text/html]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

i am calling a rest API with below `restTemplate` set up. API is returning response of type `[text/html]`  but i am not able to convert it into

```
 RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String url = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(host + "/api").toUriString();
    HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
    Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter jaxbMessageConverter = new Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter();
    List<MediaType> mediaTypes = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
    mediaTypes.add(MediaType.ALL);
    jaxbMessageConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(mediaTypes);
    messageConverters.add(jaxbMessageConverter);
    restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);
    requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML);
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    converter.getObjectMapper().configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(0, converter);
```

But getting below exception

```
 No HttpMessageConverter for [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode] and content type [text/html]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$HttpEntityRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:956)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:732)
```